# Keep center alignment for one element not the whole line

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to center text and put more text in the same line right next to it, while keeping the whole thing centered on the first text and not the whole line. Is there an easy way to do this?

All the solutions that I tried so far were either centering on the whole line or failed to put everything on the same line. Of course I also searched through stackoverflow but could not find a solution.
I've made this as a mockup: http://jsfiddle.net/mzqC5/ 
The way it should behave is that the alignment is centered on "A" and not the whole line. I'd appreciate any help with it since I've been trying to solve this for a good time now.

Thank you very much.

```
<div class="centered">A<div class="subtext">[24]</div>
```

```
.centered {
font-family: Meiryo, sans-serif;
font-size: 75px;
text-align: center;
color: black;
background-color: cornflowerblue;
max-width: 175px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.subtext {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 24px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: When you say "centered" and "aligned" - do you mean **vertically** or **horizontally**?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPCWF/)

Comment: Sorry, I meant horizontally and yes your solution is pretty much the thing I was looking for same as the guy who posted below. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to absolutely position [24] with the relatively-positioned A.

```
.centered {
    font-family: Meiryo, sans-serif;
    font-size: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    max-width: 175px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.subtext {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 24px;
}
```

[image]

Because the element is absolutely-positioned it is not in the document-flow and doesn't affect the text-alignment.

You can adjust `bottom` to move it higher up.

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much for helping me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could set it up like this (red line added just to demonstrate page center):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

div {
    text-align: center; 
    height: 100%;
}

span {
    position: relative;
}

b {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    font-weight: normal;
}


html, body {height: 100%;}
body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
div::after {content: ''; height: 100%; width: 2px; background: red; left: 50%; margin-left: -1px; position:absolute;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <span>
        A
        <b>[24]</b>
    </span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I actually went ahead and rewrote all my code for this little project today. What I came up with was this: `.span.textproperties{..} .span.positionproperty{...} and then just combine them whenever I need them: <span class id="textproperties positionproperty">`